# Inverted [Maybe a] tranverse behavior

Tags: list, haskell, option-type

I want to create a function that receives some items to process, returning `Nothing` when none of the items could be processed and `Just` if at least one item was processed.

To me, this sounds a lot like how `traverse` works for `Maybe`, but inverted, since it returns `Nothing` if at least one item was not processed and `Just` when all items were processed.

Supposing `traverseI` is my 'inverted' traverse:

```hs
myFunc :: [Int] -> Maybe [Int]
myFunc xs = traverseI (\x -> if x > 5 then Just (x+1) else Nothing) xs

myFunc [1, 3, 6, 9]  -- Just [7, 10]
myFunc [1, 2, 3]     -- Nothing
```

I'm guessing I could `mapMaybe` the values and check later if it has at least one item, but I'm wondering if there's a more 'elegant' solution.

Edit: What I'm looking is for some way to get an equivalent of this function:

```hs
traverseI :: (a -> Maybe a) -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
traverseI _ [] = Nothing
traverseI f (x:xs) = do
    let mh = f x
    let mt = traverseI f xs
    case mh of
        Nothing -> mt
        Just h -> case mt of
            Nothing -> Just [h]
            Just t -> Just (h:t)
```

Comment: Why do you want `Maybe [Int]`? What's wrong with returning an empty list?

Comment: `Just x+1` is `(Just x) + 1` which a mistake and should be `Just (x+1)` instead.

Comment: Also, if you drop the `Maybe` in the result type, then the function you are looking for is `mapMaybe` from Data.Maybe.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. @Noughtmare the return of this function will be integrated with many other functions that result `Maybe`, having the same signature would leave the code much cleaner.

Comment: Maybe you should work with `MonadFail`, of which both `Maybe` and `[]` are instances. Otherwise, just use `slapMaybe :: [a] -> Maybe [a]; slapMaybe [] = Nothing; slapMaybe xs = Just xs`

Comment: Do you mean `traverse`?

Answer (score 1):

Because `Maybe [a]` is kind of a weird type, you are unlikely to find a standard library function that does this, so you'll need to write your own... which you've already done.  I don't see anything wrong with your `traverseI`, really.

If you'd like something more succinct, then the following will work:

```
import Data.Maybe

traverseI :: (a -> Maybe a) -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
traverseI f xs = case mapMaybe f xs of
                   [] -> Nothing
                   xs -> Just xs
```

The reason that `Maybe [a]` is a "weird" type, at least for this particular application, is that the simpler type `[a]` already allows for a value, namely the empty list `[]`, that can represent the situation where none of the items can be processed.  This type is already powerful enough and doesn't "need" the extra `Maybe` wrapper and its associated `Nothing` value.